# Free UML diagram tool for Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Are there any free tools in the market which support Objective C?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you after something that generates objective C code? Or just something that can model objective C

Answer (score 2):

I use Argo UML and Violet UML for modelling on my Mac (Assuming you are using a mac). They are not great but they work.

If you want code generation that is a whole different issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked both of the tools but they were not able to provide me what i was looking for. Basiaclly there are certain things within Objective C which cannot come in standard UML program, i used netbeans for making UML previosuly, mainly java programs. But in objective C there is @property and other things which dont map on standard UML diagram tools, so i am looking for which can help in modeling Objective C classes. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, one of the points of UML is to be language-agnostic. 
If what you're asking is if any of the available tools supports Obj-C code generation: Googling, you can find some (commercial) tools that claim to offer Objective-C code generation.

It probably makes more sense to use XCodes built-in diagramming tools, which can be found in the "Design" menu. These are not, strictly speaking UML, but are quite similar.

Also, UML might not be such a good fit for designing Cocoa / Objective-C applications, because mostly you will use Model-View-Controller, into which a UML diagram doesn't offer much additional insight.

Comment: I have seen the tool which is within XCode but it can only make diagrams for your project, but you can use it otherwise, i mean use it to make ER diagrams. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, XCode 3.2 had a class editor that did what is being asked for.  In Xcode 4.0 and later we can only use it for core-data related tasks which is a shame.  I have a similar need as I have a team member that prefers diagrams to code.

I don't understand why it was removed.  I'm hoping that I can find it as a standalone tool within the Apple Developer member center, but I don't have high hopes.

Worst case, you can download XCode 3.2, install it alongside 4, and use the editor within 3.2.

I have tried this very briefly.  So long as you don't try to open the file under 4, I think it works, though I'd be wary of opening your 4-based project in 3.2.

Hope this helps.